# get outlook to fire vba script on old emails

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I have wrote some vba in outlook that fires when a new email comes in. However I want to fire it on an old email for testing. Can anyone tell me how.

my current code is

```
Private Sub objInbox_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it thanks.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set objInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
'Call test
   'MsgBox "outlook starting"
End Sub
Sub test()
    MsgBox "in test"
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim item As Object
    Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
     'Dim sub_folder As MAPIFolder

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
     'Set sub_folder = inbox.Folders("TEST")

    For Each item In inbox.Items
    If TypeOf item Is MailItem Then
        MsgBox "right subject"
    End If
    Next item
End Sub
```